page transition not working properly in nested routes in nest.js
I implemented a page transition, it works perfectly, the only problem is when you navigate from a nested route to a non-nested route like /projects/[category]/[slug] to /projects only enter animation is play, while exit is not played. The following is the version of my next.js and framer motion. My Operating System is Windows. Moreover I'm not using app router, its pages router.
// src/components/Transition.jsx
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import Footer from "./Footer";

export const perspective = {
  initial: {
    scale: 0.95,
    opacity: 0.5,
    y: 150,
  },
  enter: {
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      duration: 1.2,
      ease: [0.76, 0, 0.24, 1],
    },
  },
  exit: {
    scale: 0.95,
    y: 150,
    opacity: 0.5,
    transition: {
      duration: 1.2,
      ease: [0.76, 0, 0.24, 1],
    },
  },
};

export const slide = {
  initial: {
    y: 0,
  },
  enter: {
    y: "-100vh",
    transition: {
      duration: 1,
      ease: [0.76, 0, 0.24, 1],
    },
  },
  exit: {
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      duration: 1,
      ease: [0.76, 0, 0.24, 1],
    },
  },
};

const anim = (variants) => {
  return {
    initial: "initial",
    animate: "enter",
    exit: "exit",
    variants,
  };
};

export default function Transition({ children }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentScrollY = window.scrollY;

    return () => {
      window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollY);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-black dark:bg-white overflow-hidden">
      <motion.div
        className="h-screen w-full fixed top-0 left-0 bg-white dark:bg-black z-10"
        {...anim(slide)}
      />
      <motion.div
        className="bg-white dark:bg-black transition-colors duration-500"
        {...anim(perspective)}
      >
        <NavBar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}


//app.js
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";
import { Plus_Jakarta_Sans, Inter } from "next/font/google";

const plus_Jakarta_Sans = Plus_Jakarta_Sans({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800"],
  variable: "--font-plus-jakarta-sans",
});

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800"],
  variable: "--font-inter",
});

export default function App({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
    return (
    <div className={`${plus_Jakarta_Sans.variable} ${inter.variable}`}>
      <ThemeProvider attribute="class">

        <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
      
          <Component key={router.route} {...pageProps} />
       
        </AnimatePresence>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

    "framer-motion": "^11.5.4",
    "next": "14.2.8",

I Tried to change the key and the mode of AnimatePresence, but nothing worked
<Component key={router.asPath} {...pageProps} />
<AnimatePresence mode="sync">
<AnimatePresence mode="popLayout">
          <Component
            key={`${router.asPath}-${
              router.query.slug || router.query.Category
            }`}
            {...pageProps}
          />

I expected that this problem might resolve if I experiment with key or mode, but nothing worked.

I see you try to give relevant information. Is it possible to make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?
